# What are the counterparts of innerXml and outerXml in XDocument?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to refactor some code that uses XmlDocument class to Linq To Xml. But, I'm not sure what are the counterparts of innerXml and outerXml in XDocument?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per MSDN, [`InnerXml`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.innerxml.aspx) return markup of children of the current node and [`OuterXml`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.outerxml.aspx) return markup of *current node and* all it's children.

So, to get a string result similar to `OuterXml`, you can try using simple `ToString()` method. But there is no built in method that return a result similar to `InnerXml`. Possible way to emulate `InnerXml` functionality is, by calling `ToString()` for each child of current node, then join those strings into single string result :

```
XDocument xdoc;
........
var currentNode = xdoc.Root;
var innerXml = string.Join("", currentNode.Elements().Select(o => o.ToString()));
```

You can optionally make above code an extension method for `XElement` to make it more handy to use.

Comment: I think there is a built-in method that returns a result similar to `InnerXml`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xelement.value is documented as: "Gets or sets the concatenated text contents of this element."